# Best-effort save with mongoose MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am saving logs to MongoDB. Obviously, these logs are ideally going to be generated perfect and error-free, but the whole idea of logs is to track down issues, so when there are issues I need the logs to do their best to save, even if the data is invalid.

Sometimes, objects are saved to the logs, and sometimes those objects are recursively dependant on themselves. Obviously, I can't save recursive objects to MongoDB (at least not easily), so Mongo throws an error explaining this to me and *does not save those logs*.

What I want is some way to tell mongo to Save and simply throw away any data that can't be validated rather than throwing an error.

Note: Fundamentally, I'm looking for a way to make this system impenetrable to bugs, so that it always saves no matter what. This is our primary debugging tool, so it needs to be robust.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can try `JSON.stringify(obj)` prior to saving to detect problems earlier

Comment: This is true, but what I'm looking for is a solution that will mean, no matter how much garbage gets thrown at the logs, it always at least saves something. There are potential other problems where schema verification will fail, but I don't want anything to stop at least the good part of the logs saving. I'm hoping Mongo has some built-in feature I just haven't been able to find.